# Does setting a connection speed in Steam limit bandwidth usage?

Tags: steam

I always assumed that the speed setting is only informational and is used for download time estimates. I have never seen anything that would suggest otherwise - until I read [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3173/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-download-bandwidth-used-by-steam/3178#3178). I still don't believe that it is used as a cap; however I also think the remaining time estimate is computed from the current speed. How it really is?

Comment: A supplementary question might then be, if it _is_ computed from the current speed, what is that setting used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that the Steam connection settings are used in any meaningful way to effect download speeds.  I know they are part of the [Steam Hardware Survey](http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey), but your download speed is simply a factor of the maximum speed your connection to the Steam servers can sustain.

The "Time Left" is a reflection of the amount of data left to transfer, and recent instantaneous speeds between your machine and the Steam servers.

Comment: So it's what I thought; I just forgot about the hardware survey. Thanks. :)