# How can I throttle Steam?

Tags: steam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to limit the download bandwidth used by Steam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3173/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-download-bandwidth-used-by-steam)

For my housemate's sake, I'd like to throttle Steam's download speed (when downloading games). How can I do that?

Also because I have a fast internet connection but a slow (relative to most gamers) computer, when Steam is downloading at 3 MB/s , my computer is unresponsive and unusable.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a third party program to forcibly limit Steam's downloading speed. I've been using a program called [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) for a while now, which allows for program-specific download/upload speed caps. It's useful for a variety of other applications as well.

Comment: NetLimiter might work - but is overkill considering Steam has the feature built-in. See the duplicate question for the full answer.

Comment: @zaTrickyat the time that this question was asked and answered, Steam didn't have it built in. Of course, now that it exists, it's easy :P

Comment: Erm ... Fair point! xD